# CF - Application installation CAB (including .net cf ...)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, installation, cab

Can some1 please explain how can i include this installations in my CAB file.

NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab
NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab

Also on some devices the user has to confirm several DLLs that i would like to awoid.
Im told that i should use ILMerge, but i dont know exactly what to do.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever told you that ILMerge was a solution obviously doesn't know anything about CF development or CAB files.  It won't do you any good, so don't waste time looking into it.

Microsoft published an [MSDN article that covers multi-CAB installs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158796.aspx), which would be a very good first start.  THen look at [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raffael/archive/2008/07/22/silently-install-multiple-cabs-on-windows-mobile.aspx) about how to modify it.

As for avoiding confirmations, [wcelaod.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158700.aspx) (the app that unpacks the CAB on the device) has command line options to prevent them.

**EDIT**

The sample source code for multicabinstall ships with the WinMo SDKs.  FOr example, if you installed the WInMo 6.0 SDK in its default location, the source will be at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\Common\CPP\Win32\multicabinstall`

Comment: Thanx again for your anwser ctacke ! But on the MSDN page i cannot find the source. Also a question with wcelaod.exe ... so after i build my install project that puts our the .cab file i just run wceload command with the parameters on the given .cab file?

Comment: or do i need to handle wceload somewhere in my setup project (like ce_setup.h file)?